# sidekiq - WARN: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

It shows wrong number of arguments but I am passing 3 arguments

```
ScannerWorker.perform_async('bob1','bob2',5)
```

Here sidekiq worker code

```
  class ScannerWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(bob1, bob2, bob3)
    puts bob1
  end
end
```

sidekiq version:- 4.2.7
rails 4.2.6
Redis server v=3.0.7

Sidekiq Error:-

```
2017-01-03T06:29:43.007Z 9547 TID-itjjk WARN: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2..3)
2017-01-03T06:29:43.007Z 9547 TID-itjjk WARN: /home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/app/workers/scanner_worker.rb:5:in `test'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/app/workers/scanner_worker.rb:5:in `perform'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:158:in `execute_job'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:138:in `block (4 levels) in process'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:36:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:133:in `block (3 levels) in process'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:128:in `block in invoke'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/active_record.rb:6:in `call'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb:74:in `call'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:11:in `block in call'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/logging.rb:32:in `with_context'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/logging.rb:7:in `call'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:130:in `block in invoke'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/middleware/chain.rb:133:in `invoke'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:132:in `block (2 levels) in process'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:174:in `stats'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:131:in `block in process'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq.rb:35:in `block in <module:Sidekiq>'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:126:in `process'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:82:in `process_one'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/processor.rb:70:in `run'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:17:in `watchdog'
/home/smk/14.04/rails/projects/myappname/vendor/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.7/lib/sidekiq/util.rb:25:in `block in safe_thread'
```

Comment: Try restarting Sidekiq...

Comment: and try restarting raisl server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restart Sidekiq

To Start:

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq
```

To Run in the background:

```
$ bundle exec sidekiq -d -P tmp/sidekiq.pid -L log/sidekiq.log
```

where `-d` demonize, `-P` pid file, `-L` log file.

Stop:

```
$ bundle exec sidekiqctl stop tmp/sidekiq.pid 0
```

Sidekiq shut down gracefully.
where 0 is number of seconds to wait until Sidekiq exits.

Answer (score 3):

You need to restart Sidekiq.  Live code reloading only works with Sidekiq 4.2+ running **Rails 5.0+**.

Answer (score 2):

Follow this steps
* Mention the sidekiq version in gemfile
* kill the sidekiq process and restart the sidekiq

Answer (score 0):

worth noting.  I've been working on a similar issue.

```
SomeWorker.perform_async(@user.id)

  class SomeWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    puts "{user_id}"
  end
end
```

unsure exactly why i was getting the arguments error. Maybe it was an because of an instance variable, maybe a rails bug.
Nevertheless, I receated the worker using

```
 $rails g sidekiq:worker SomeWorker
```

and saw this *.

```
  class SomeWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(*args)
    puts #some thing
  end
end
```

by adding the astrix everything worked perfectly.

quick answer:

```
 class SomeWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(*user_id)
    puts #some thing
  end
end
```